# How to assign a different process for each object's instance ? Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently working on a Python driver which wraps a C code used to acquire data from a phasemeter.

It is currently working fine with 1 phasemeter however I need to acquire data from 4 phasemeter at the same time. As there is a huge flow a data for each of them I came up with the idea of running them on different process. So far I understand running programs on different processes use different memory parts and will help to avoid mixing data.

So, my idea would be to create an instance of Phasemeter object for each phasemeter and assign a process for each instance.
I already tried to use multiprocessing or Taskset however the first one is used for functions (as far as I understood) and the second one only assign programs and not instances (also as far as I understood).

I am looking for any advice or hints/keywords on my Python code or to find a solution.
Thank you for your time and help.

**Python Driver Code :**

```
#%% Module import
import signal
import ctypes
import os
import sys
import json

#%% Constant definition.

# Opening config File
PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE="config/config.json"
ConfigFile = open(PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE, "r")
jsonContent = ConfigFile.read()
Config = json.loads(jsonContent)

# Path to configuration File 
PATH_TO_CFG_FILE=Config['PATH_TO_CFG_FILE']

# Path to log File 
PATH_TO_LOG_FILE=Config['PATH_TO_LOG_FILE']

# Path to Shared Object File 
PATH_TO_SO_FILE=Config["PATH_TO_SO_FILE"]
SO_NAMEFILE=Config["SO_NAMEFILE"]

# Wrapper's name 
PROGRAM_NAME=str(__file__)

#%% Class definiton
class Phasemeter :
    """ This class is a driver for XXXX Phasemeters data acquisiton """

    def __init__(self) :
        """ This method define path, enables interuptions of C code and defines C code signature
            TODO : Paralelization
        """

        # Defining path
        self.path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),PATH_TO_SO_FILE))
        self.libname = SO_NAMEFILE
        self.LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(self.path,self.libname))

    # Configuring signal to enable interuption of C_Code
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_DFL)

    # Settings C library's signature datatype
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.argtypes= [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),]
        self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main.restypes =[ctypes.c_int,]

    def start(self,*args,**kwargs):
        """ This method starts acquisition for the Phasemeter. It handles options and launches the Phasemeter's C code for acquisiiton.
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Optional arguments      | fsampling     : Sampling frequency (default is 0.0)                   -> my_phasemeter.start(fsampling=#value)
                    | vcal      : Calibration Voltage                           -> my_phasemeter.start(vcal=#value)
                    | trun      : Specify acquisition time (default is 0.0 and -1 is infinite)      -> my_phasemeter.start(trun=#value)
                    | intclk    : Call internal clock (unstable)                    -> my_phasemeter.start("intclk")
                    | comment   : Add a comment to the data file's header               -> my_phasemeter.start(comment="#your_comment")
                    | erase     : Erase previous Data file without asking permission (default is off)   -> my_phasemeter.start("erase")
                    | help      : Call c code's help (not very usefull to use the wrapper)      -> my_phasemeter.start("help")
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Method call examples    : my_phasemeter.start()
                    : my_phasemeter.start("erase",fsampling=100,trun=50,comment="Test")
                    : my_phasemeter.start("help")
                    : my_phasemeter.start("intclk","erase",comment="Test",fsampling=100,trun=100,vcal=2)
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            """
        # Robustness 
        for argument in args :
            if type(argument) is not str :
                sys.tracebacklimit = 0
                raise TypeError("Wrong type for argument ",argument, ", only strings are authorized")
        for argument in kwargs : 
            if argument in ["fsampling","vcal"] and int(kwargs[argument]) < 0 :
                raise ValueError('Please enter a positive number for keyword ',argument) 
            if argument == "comment" and type(kwargs[argument]) is not str :
                raise TypeError('Please enter a string for comment keyword, for e.g. : comment="Test"')
            if argument == "trun" and int(kwargs[argument]) < -1 :
                raise ValueError('Please enter a positive number for keyword trun or -1 for infinite acquisition time')

        # Changing data structure to fit Marshalling

    # Here we want to mimic C code's argv
        args_list=[]
        args_list.append(PROGRAM_NAME)
        args_list.append(PATH_TO_CFG_FILE)
        args_list.append(PATH_TO_LOG_FILE)

        # Handling optionnal arguments
        for argument in args :
            if argument == "erase" or "help" or "intclk" :
                args_list.append(str("--"+str(argument)))

        for argument in kwargs :
            if argument == "fsampling" or "vcal" or "comment" or "trun" :
                args_list.append(str("--"+str(argument)))
                args_list.append(str(kwargs[argument]))

        args_list=[*args_list]
        args=args_list

        # Debug
        print("Args : ",*args)

        # Marshalling data for C library
        self.c_char_pointer_array = ctypes.c_char_p * len(args)
        self.encoded_args_list= [str.encode(str(i)) for i in args ]
        self.arguments = self.c_char_pointer_array (*self.encoded_args_list)

        # Calling C library
        self.status = self.LIBC.lisaf_phasemeter_main(len(self.arguments),self.arguments,None)
```

Edit : I tried to write a little program to create each class's on different CPU or at least different process however I don't understand the result of it.

**Python program to create each instance on different process :**

```
import multiprocessing 
import os 

class Dog() :
    def __init__ (self,name) : 
        self.name = name
        Dog.info(self)
    def info(self):
        self.pid=os.getpid()
        self.ppid=os.getppid()
        print("Name : ",self.name)
        print(" PID : ", self.pid)
        print(" PPID : ", self.ppid)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print("Variable creation")
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as Process :
        Max,Leon,Bob,Leonard = Process.map(Dog,["Max","Leon","Bob","Leonard"])
    print("End of variable creation")
    print("Displaying variable info")
    print()
    print('Max info: ')
    print(Max.info())
    print()
    print('Leon info: ')
    print(Leon.info())
    print()
    print('Bob info: ')
    print(Bob.info())
    print()
    print('Leonard info: ')
    print(Leonard.info())
```

**Output :**

```
Variable creation
Name :  Max
 PID :  5717
 PPID :  5716
Name :  Leon
 PID :  5718
 PPID :  5716
Name :  Leonard
Name :  Bob
 PID :  5719
 PPID :  5716
 PID :  5717
 PPID :  5716
End of variable creation
Displaying variable info

Max info: 
Name :  Max
 PID :  5716
 PPID :  5126
None

Leon info: 
Name :  Leon
 PID :  5716
 PPID :  5126
None

Bob info: 
Name :  Bob
 PID :  5716
 PPID :  5126
None

Leonard info: 
Name :  Leonard
 PID :  5716
 PPID :  5126
None
```

Why do they have a different process at declaration and when I call it again ?

Comment: as far as I know you can simply do this: `target=Class`, should work, I mean the target should simply be called which means this happens: `Class()` so it will be run in the other process, the question is if it can be run in the other process because of pickling issues also remember to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, do you mean that if I put target = Class I will have a different process for each instance ? 
Don't worry for `if __name__ == '__main__':` I just didn't show the part with it here because it's not relevant

Comment: you'd probably need to create a loop and create 4 such processes, but yes then you should have 4 processes that each are running their own instance

Comment: Hey, I tried what you said but something goes weird so I have a new question, see the edit. Thank you for your time

Comment: I have no idea why they have different ids, I can guess that it is because the second time you check the info somehow comes from the current process (maybe that is how it should be???) (because they all have the exact same ids while first time calling them they have somewhat different ones), other guess is this: `Dog.info(self)` when it should be this: `self.info()` (but they both should be the exact same thing so I doubt that is the issue)